# ValidationMessages not updating with Spring Boot, remains cached

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, bean-validation

I am using javax validations and have set a resource bundle (property file) for some different languages. I created one for `javax.validation.constraints.Size.message` in french and it worked - it used my text. But then I made a change and it is not taking the change. The text it returns is still the original one.

I've tried:

- Restarting IntelliJ
- Rebuilding the project
- Invalidating the cache nad restarting IntelliJ
- Deleting the out/build directories
- Running ./gradlew clean

Nothing has worked so far. (I am running it in IntelliJ via the debug-run)

The field:

```
@Size(min = 3, max = 3, message = "{javax.validation.constraints.Size.message}")
private String currencyCode;
```

Th resource bundle has:

```
javax.validation.constraints.Size.message = La taille de {0} doit être comprise entre {min} et {max}
```

It used to have:

```
javax.validation.constraints.Size.message = La taille doit être comprise entre {min} et {max}
```

And that's the message I continue to see. (I was running it in Postman, but even doing it via cURL gives the same old result, so it's cached server-side - which is just localhost)

How do I clear the old value and force it to reload? Where is it caching it?

(When I look in the out and build directories, it has the new value in the properties file)